# UTC Timestamp Issue for MySQL and Postgres

Tags: mysql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using a Spring Boot framework for developing my Backend API where I require the UTC Timestamp inorder to delete expired entries (UTC Timestamp is required because I'm using `Instant()` in java which uses UTC Timestamp). Problem arises as because I'm using a MySQL Database for my development environment which uses `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` to get the utc time stamp, while my Postgres Database on my Production Development Server uses `AT TIME ZONE UTC`. How can I get UTC Timestamp for both the database using JPA Query.

I tried using the `application.properties` file to set the command to get current date but could find a way to use it in the repository as they are interface.

I'm having a field which stores the time of expiry of certain record for this purpose I used `Instant.now().plusMillis()` to get the time. But when I need to find expired accounts I'm unable as the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is giving me the Local Timestamp but the one which I stored is in `UTC_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that getting the time on the Java side (through `Instant.now()`) doesn’t suffice for you? That you need the time according to the database server?

Comment: I'm having a field which stores the time of expiry of certain record for this purpose I used ```Instant.now().plusMillis()``` to get the time. But when I need to find expired accounts I'm unable as the ```CURRENT_TIMESTAMP``` is giving me the Local Timestamp but the one which I stored is in ```UTC_TIMESTAMP```.

Comment: I suppose a hack would be to pass the current UTC time from Java and use it for comparison. But it’s not what you want.